# How to solve a conflict between browserify (Backbone based app) and require.js on the same page?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js, browserify

I have a backbone app up and running correctly. It's meant to be used as a widget in 3rd pages. Unfortunately, I just realised that one of these pages has already Backbone / underscore loaded.

I get errors such as this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
```

Which usually appear when underscore has not been previously loaded.

My typical view is like this: (normal Backbone view)

./view1.js

```
var Backbone = require('backbone')
var _ = require('underscore')
var $ = require('jquery')
Backbone.$ = $

module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {

  },

  initialize: function () {

  },

  render: function () {

  }
})
```

then I just have to call it:

```
var View1 = require('view1')
var view1Instance = new View1(...)
```

Thanks for any help :)

EDIT after investigation:
When running through the debugger, it appears that the `Backbone` variable is an empty object instead of being Backbone. As if the `require('backbone')` just returned `{}`

EDIT2:
It seems related to this issue: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/790

Comment: Can you give us more details about the error? Is it `Backbone.View.extend` that fails?

Comment: @ben The error that I mention occurs at `module.exports = Backbone.View.extend` (I also edited the question)

Comment: That empty object usually occurs when you have a circular dependencies. But that should not happen when requiring Backbone. Also, noConflict shouldn't matter as technically everything in a bundle is closured off from the rest of the environment.

Comment: Could it be related to the fact that they use require.js ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with Backbone and Requirejs ([as indicated by thlorenz here](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/790))

> - backbone looks for `define` before looking for module.exports
> - requirejs works with globals which is not good practice and in this case causes problems since it affects everything that runs in the same
>     browser tab

He advises to wrap everything in a scope and hide the `define` function.
He has also a tool to do that.[browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim)

However I did not use that but the postBundleCB option from Browserify: (thx to a coworker).

In my `Gruntfile`:

```
browserify: {
  dist: {
    src: ['src/app/app.js'],
    dest: 'www/app.js',
    options: {
      postBundleCB: function (err, src, next) {
        return next(null, '(function () { var define = undefined; '+src+' })();')
      }
    }
  }
},
```

This solved my problem :)

I didn't try browserify-shim, so I don't know much about it.

Comment: This was by far the easiest way for me to fix requirejs conflicts with my library (browserified). @balazs solution also works, but I like the approach of wrapping my code instead of placing something before it (though if you already have a self executing anonymous function in your code this could be repetitive).

Comment: Thanks for this. I was getting `Fatal error: The "list[1]" argument must be one of type Array, Buffer, or Uint8Array. Received type string` wrapping the code in a buffer resolved this for me `return next(null, Buffer.from('(function () { var define = undefined; '+src.toString()+' })();'))`

Answer (score 3):

In case someone is using gulp and the official browserify (so postBundleCB is not available) I used [gulp-wrap](https://github.com/adamayres/gulp-wrap) to wrap the 'define' definition:

```
var wrap = require('gulp-wrap');

[...]

bundler.bundle()
  .on('error', swallowError)
  .pipe(source(file))
  .pipe(wrap('(function () { var define = undefined; <%=contents%> })();'))
  .pipe(rename(renameOptions))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(argv.output?argv.output:'./dist'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround would be using a custom prelude like this:

```
// modules are defined as an array
// [ module function, map of requireuires ]
//
// map of requireuires is short require name -> numeric require
//
// anything defined in a previous bundle is accessed via the
// orig method which is the requireuire for previous bundles

(function outer (modules, cache, entry) {
    // Save the require from previous bundle to this closure if any
    var previousRequire = typeof require == "function" && require;

    function newRequire(name, jumped){
        var oldDefine = window.define;
        window.define = undefined;
        if(!cache[name]) {
            if(!modules[name]) {
                // if we cannot find the the module within our internal map or
                // cache jump to the current global require ie. the last bundle
                // that was added to the page.
                var currentRequire = typeof require == "function" && require;
                if (!jumped && currentRequire) return currentRequire(name, true);

                // If there are other bundles on this page the require from the
                // previous one is saved to 'previousRequire'. Repeat this as
                // many times as there are bundles until the module is found or
                // we exhaust the require chain.
                if (previousRequire) return previousRequire(name, true);
                var err = new Error('Cannot find module \'' + name + '\'');
                err.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND';
                throw err;
            }
            var m = cache[name] = {exports:{}};
            modules[name][0].call(m.exports, function(x){
                var id = modules[name][1][x];
                return newRequire(id ? id : x);
            },m,m.exports,outer,modules,cache,entry);
        }
        window.define = oldDefine;
        return cache[name].exports;
    }
    for(var i=0;i<entry.length;i++) newRequire(entry[i]);

    // Override the current require with this new one
    return newRequire;
})
```

and you can give this prelude for browserify like this:

```
browserify({
  prelude: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/src/js/prelude.js', 'utf-8'),
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be related to someone, who is using browserify in a site that has requirejs. A provisional solution can be, instead of :

```
`.pipe(wrap('(function () { var define = undefined; <%=contents%> })();'))`
```

for someone who is using the browserify API directly, can add this little piece of code before load our bundle:

```
(function() {
if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define.amd= false; 
}})();
```

this will allow to continue with our execution, without break the code on the client side.

I hope that this be useful.