# ES6 imports and require not working properly with gulp/browserify/babelify

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I have a simple Gulp configuration to transpile my javascript with babel :

```
gulp.task('js_dev', function () {
    var bundler = browserify({entries: ['js/index.js'], debug: true});
    bundler.external('jquery');
    return bundler
        .transform("babelify", {presets: ["es2015"]})
        .bundle()
        .on('error', function (err) {
            console.error(err);
            this.emit('end');
        })
        .pipe(source('dev.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(jsdest));
});
```

With this, I can import my development files.
But I can't import some package installed with npm (isotope, textfit, babel-polyfill...).

For example, if I import babel-polyfill in my index.js file :

```
import "babel-polyfill";
```

No errors with gulp, and the code seems to be added in dev.js, but it's not working, and I can't require it either : it gives an empty Object.

Same things for other npm modules (isotope for example). When I `require` them, it just gives an empty object. And Isotope is supposed to work with require.

Any idea what's happening ?

Thanks.

Comment: `babel-polyfill` doesn't export anything...

Comment: Maybe, but isotope does (or should). And babel-polyfill should allow me to use for...of loops, right ? If if do a for...loop just after the import, it gives my a xxx[Symbol.operator] is not a function.

Comment: Here is the generated code for :

    `import "babel-polyfill";

    for (let t of {'test':1}){
        alert(t)
    }`

: http://pastebin.com/pQUDLpYg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found it.
My JavaScript files were added to a CMS which already used AMD/Require.js. This conflicts with browserify.

The solution [was here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35230300/6770982).

Answer (score 0):

What about doing:

```
import BabelPolyfill from "babel-polyfill"
```

Comment: It makes no difference.

Comment: So did it in the end? :)